# Tabs and filters disappear from embedded quicksight dashboard on mobile

Tags: amazon-web-services, quicksight-embedding

When I am looking at a quicksight embedded dashboard on a mobile the quicksight tabs and filters are missing.

I included scrolling: "yes" but that does not solve the problem.

```js
function embedDashboard(embedUrl) {
                var containerDiv = document.getElementById("dashboardContainer");
                var params = {
                    url: embedUrl,
                    container: containerDiv,
                    height: "800px",
            scrolling: "yes"
                };
                var dashboard = QuickSightEmbedding.embedDashboard(params);
                dashboard.on('error', onError);
                dashboard.on('load', onVisualLoaded);
            }
```